# Posting data from more input tags inside PHP while Loop using POST or GET without JS

Tags: php, html

I am trying to update Payed Price and Payed Date in any row in my HTMl table.
I am using this table to see invoices which must be payed and I have add option to pay only part of the price. User will be able to wrote any price in the input field and also pick the date when the price was payed. Then after user will hit Submit Button I want update my database with these new data.
But I have problem to pass this data.
I really do not know if I can use GET method for this or only POST method with form.

```
$AktualDate = date('Y-m-d');

$sqli = "SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE Price != PayedPrice";                  
     $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){ 

        echo"
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Firm</th>
            <th>Price</th>          
            <th>Payed Price</th>
            <th>Payed Date</th>
        </tr>               
            ";

        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){

            $ID = $rows['ID'];
            $Firm = $rows['Firm'];
            $Price = $rows['Price'];
            $PayedPrice = $rows['PayedPrice '];
            $PayedDate = $rows['PayedDate '];

            echo"
            <tr>
            <form>";?><form action="payed.php" method="GET">
                <?php echo"
                <td>$ID</td>
                <td>$Firm</td>
                <td>$Price</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='PayedPrice ' value=".$PayedPrice ."></td>
                <td><input type='date' name='PayedDate ' value=".$AktualDate."></td>
                <td><button type='submit' name='pay'>PAY</button></td>          
            </form>
            </tr>

            ";
        }?>
        </table>
```

In payed.php file I have simple code

```
if(isset($_GET['pay']))
    {

            $ID = $_GET['ID'];
            $PayedPrice= $_GET['PayedPrice'];
            $PayedDate = $_GET['PayedDate '];

        $sql = "UPDATE invoice SET PayedDate = '".$PayedDate ."', PayedPrice= '".$PayedPrice."' WHERE ID = '".$ID."'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql );

    }
?>
```

Now when I hit Button I am getting only some "strange" update in my url which add this ?PayedPrice=4545&PayedDAte=2019-04-07&pay=
But problem is that whole page is not reloading and I see that I am not passing these data to my next php file.
Is there some solution WITHOUT using JS, JQuery etc?

thx

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<?php
$AktualDate = date('Y-m-d');
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE Price != PayedPrice";                  
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){ 
    echo"
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Firm</th>
            <th>Price</th>          
            <th>Payed Price</th>
            <th>Payed Date</th>
        </tr>               
    ";
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        $ID = $rows['ID'];
        $Firm = $rows['Firm'];
        $Price = $rows['Price'];
        $PayedPrice = $rows['PayedPrice '];
        $PayedDate = $rows['PayedDate '];
        echo"
        <tr>";
    ?>
        <form action="payed.php" method="GET">
        <?php echo"
            <td>" . $ID . "</td>
            <td>" . $Firm . "</td>
            <td>" . $Price . "</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='PayedPrice ' value=" . $PayedPrice . "></td>
            <td><input type='date' name='PayedDate ' value=" . $AktualDate . "></td>
            <td><button type='submit' name='pay'>PAY</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    ";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi I am getting this error  Notice: Undefined index: ID in /var/www...../payed.php on line 25. This mean that I am not passing also ID value? Correct? I have add one more code  line above <td>" . $ID . "</td>. Looks like this: <input type='hidden' name='ID' value=".$ID.">  But I really do not know if this is good solution...